# Terminal do VSCode com codificação inadequada

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

Estou usando o Visual Studio Code para as minhas aulas de C, mas estou me incomodando muito com o terminal. Ele está usando alguma codificação que não admite acentos e isso está comprometendo a visualização dos resultados dos meus programas. Segue um screenshot.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que apenas a saída está errada; os diretórios, que não fazem parte do código mesmo, exibem os acentos tranquilamente.